# Jmeter not showing up proper response instead giving details of server and connection details

Tags: api, https, jmeter, response, oauth-1.0a

I am using Jmeter 5.4.1 version, my API is of oauth1.0 type. When I ran my api through postman , it gave my proper json response for example an proper id, but the same api when ran through jmeter gives 200 response code but giving details of server and connection in response body and not the reponse that is expected(a proper id).

Below is the response :

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Wed, 12 May 2021 12:33:10 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=eqvp0l22u2jo30moqn194meugp; expires=Wed, 12-May-2021 13:33:10 GMT; Max-Age=3600; path=/; domain=dev.moorup.no; HttpOnly
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Cache-Control: no-store
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qK6vZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at `Response Headers` tab of the [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener therefore you're seeing the [HTTP Response Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Response_header)

Just switch to `Response Body` tab and you will be able to see "raw" HTML Response and several options of rendering it:

[image]

Also be aware that it is possible to [convert your Postman scripts to JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling), for OAuth you will still have to do some [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start), but for the main logic record and replay should work more or less fine